# Absolutely positioned element moved by margin of another element

Tags: css, positioning, margin, absolute

Here is my jsFiddle for the following question: http://jsfiddle.net/arelia/Rruxf/

I'd like to have a header that stays at the very top of the body and a footer that stays at the very bottom of the body. I have a content div (position: relative) between the header and footer, and when I set a margin around the div my absolutely positioned header and footer move from their top/bottom positions by the height of that margin (this also happened when I tried setting a margin above and below the paragraphs in the div). In the fiddle you can see that the footer is not attached to the bottom even though it's absolutely positioned (I went ahead and made the header static since static gives the intended result). **How do I position the header and footer to the top and bottom of the body and not have the content in the middle move those two elements?** If the position: absolute elements are moved out of the flow why would anything affect their position at all?

I've tried searching here and Google for "CSS margin affects absolute" and a few other phrases to no avail. I discovered this while playing around with it some more in developer tools:

- Metrics show the body is the height of the html element minus the amount of one margin (the margin that's still affecting the footer). So, the body must be stretching to the height of the content div since there is nothing else within the document flow within the body to define its height. But that height ends where the content ends instead of after the margin. Shouldn't it include the margin?
- If I make the height of the body 100%, the footer positions
  itself to the bottom of the viewport and then stays fixed in that
  spot when I scroll. Why isn't it attaching itself to the bottom of
  the body instead of the bottom of the viewport?

Comment: Any reason you have the footer absolutly positioned in the first place? It's already at the bottom, where you want it.

Comment: Thanks, @sachleen. It's because I don't want the footer positioned immediately after the content. If the content is short I want the footer at the bottom of the viewport. If the content is long I want it to follow the content and touch the bottom left and right corners of the page. Does that make sense? Here I forked the jsFiddle and explicitly made the footer static. It's positioned correctly with lots of content but with little content it's not at the very bottom of the viewport: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tfFA2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your commment I think I understand what you're trying to achieve. You can use this:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Here is how you could integrate it with your existing code:

http://jsfiddle.net/wJSZD/

Comment: Thanks for Sticky Footer. @ScottS your answer was also great and I considered that solution while reading the information for Sticky Footer but in my full project my interior content has a border and background color that would still overlap the footer if I used the padding solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer to Your Two Last Questions

- "But that height [of the body] ends where the content ends instead of after the margin. Shouldn't it include the margin?" *Answer*: No, the `body` height itself is unaffected by the bottom margin of an element within it.
- "If I make the height of the body 100% ... Why isn't it attaching itself to the bottom of the body instead of the bottom of the viewport?" *Answer*: It *is* attaching to the bottom of the `body` because by setting height to `100%` you have set the `body` to the viewport height.

### Answer to Your Main Questions in Reverse Order

- "If the position: absolute elements are moved out of the flow why would anything affect their position at all?" *Answer*: What affects their position is the position of that body element. In taking the answer to the first question above, that margin on an inner element can cause the element within the the `body` to keep off the bottom of the viewport, and thus cause the `body` itself to gap from the bottom of the viewport by that distance. Then, when you position an element to the `body`, it will be gapped because the body is not flush to the bottom of the viewport. This is what you are seeing in the footer area of your fiddle.
- "How do I position the header and footer to the top and bottom of the body and not have the content in the middle move those two elements?" *Answer*: Adam's original answer of `fixed` is one method, based strictly off your bolded question (he has since modified it). However, you clarified in a comment that you really want is "If the content is short I want the footer at the bottom of the viewport. If the content is long I want it to follow the content and touch the bottom left and right corners of the page." Adam's original answer of `fixed` positioning will not accomplish that (as he also realized). Rather:

### Do This

```css
html {height: 100%}
body {min-height: 100%;}

div {
    margin: 20px 20px 0 20px; /* eliminate your bottom margin */
    padding-bottom: 50px; /* use bottom padding to get space for footer */
}
```

[See short content fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Rruxf/3/)

[See long content fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Rruxf/2/)

Comment: Thanks also for the thorough explanation to all of the questions. Although I'll have to explore your first answers more later. I found that when I add a border to the body there's no margin gap at the bottom ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/arelia/TCsgp/)) so I'm still confused as to why there's a margin gap ever.